# How long does it take for Name server to be active?

Tags: linux, dns, centos, plesk, nameservers

I created custom Name Servers with PLESK - two NS records (ns1, ns2) + two A records.
How long does it take for these new Name Servers to be active in order to use them in Domain cPanel? Because right now when I add them I see message, that they are not valid Name servers?

Comment: After you have registered a domain name with No-IP, it will take 24-72 hours for your domain name to propagate to all of the root DNS servers. Your domain may show up in the WHOIS database before it has fully propogated to the root DNS servers.

Comment: The domain is bought two weeks ago and has default name servers pointing to hostgator. I created my own name servers on my own server and tried to add then in the Domain Panel, but I receive error, that my name server is not valid. I created it today, so this is why I am asking when I can add my name server to my domain.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to register private/child  nameserver at your domain registrar control panel(Hostgator) as below.

ns1.yourdomain.com - Your server IP

ns2.yourdomain.com - Your server IP

Once you have registered private nameserver you can set those nameserver for your domain at domain control panel as below.

ns1.yourdomain.com

ns2.yourdomain.com

It will take around 24 to 48 hours to propagate.
Once you change nameserver you can also check it at below URL.
https://intodns.com/

For Propagation you can check at - https://www.whatsmydns.net/